# Python for loop for printing n lines after every n-th line

Tags: python, for-loop, binary

I want to loop over a binary file and print specific bytes. How can I use a for loop to print out n bytes after every n-th byte.

An example: numbers from 0...10, printing 2 numbers after every 3 numbers would equal to output: 3, 4, 8, 9.

Comment: What have your tried so far? Please provide a minimal working code snippet.

Comment: You should be able to convert that English description directly to Python. It may be clumsy Python, and you may get stuck somewhere, but at least you'll have something specific to ask about instead of just "here's my assignment, write my code for me".

Comment: to be fair to the OP- the question is explained well and is pretty clear. And here it is understandable  that the question being of a basic nature, any attempts at a solution might not have been enlightning.

[[http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284599/do-questions-have-to-have-an-attempted-solution]]

Answer (score 1):

While I don't want to encourage questions that ask for code without presenting an attempt along with expected vs actual output, I would point out that you don't have to actually change the step size of the for loop:

```
for i in xrange(3,20,5):
  print i
  print i+1
```

**[EDIT]**

Note that `xrange` is only present in python < 3, `range` has taken over that role in >= 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
def myiter(x,y,s,n):
    for i in xrange(x,y,s):
        for j in range(n):
            yield i+j
```

Sample usage:

```
In:[i for i in myiter(1,101,10,3)]
Out:[1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33, 41, 42, 43, 51, 52, 53, 61, 62, 63, 71, 72, 73, 81, 82, 83, 91, 92, 93]
```

Answer (score -1):

It's just an example with a integer list, but you can adapt it to bytes:

```
mylist = range(17)

i = 0
for value in mylist:
    if i >= 3:
        print value
    i = (i+1)%5
```

Comment: This is a tuple, not a list.

Comment: Note that in python 2.7, your first `for` loop creates a list (`range(17)`), only to iterate through it and then append those values to a second list. Unneccesary work.

Comment: How should I do that then?

Comment: `mylist = range(17)` if in python < 3, `mylist = list(range(17))` in python >= 3

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted your answer btw, since it's not actually incorrect. Merely pointing out a more efficient approach.

Comment: I always wonder why people downvote withtout saying what.
I was thinking it was you because of my mistakes, but now it's just annoying me...